# this is Arrow functions in browser is global but not in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, arrow-functions

in Google chrome

```
const ExampleObject5 = () => {
    console.log(this===window)
}

ExampleObject5()
```

Prints true

But in node

```
const ExampleObject5 = () => {
    console.log(this===global)
}

ExampleObject5()
```

Prints False

Comment: You should amend the title because it makes no sense.

Comment: see: [globalThis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis) for consolidating global access across contexts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By reading [NodeJS Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global):

> global
>
> The global namespace object.
>
> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that
> in browsers if you're in the global scope var something will define a
> global variable. In Node.js this is different. The top-level scope is
> not the global scope; var something inside an Node.js module will be
> local to that module.

So in Node the top-level scope is not the global scope (as in browser) but the module itself.